# Vim terminalの背景色を変える

Tags: vim

Vim terminal (`:terminal`)を使っているのですが、terminalの背景色が下記の写真のように灰色っぽくなってしまいます。
これを下のエディタのWindowのように白くする方法はありますか?

私の環境では、
`background=light`
`colorscheme default`
`t_Co=256`

という設定になっています

VimはCUIで起動しています

macOS: 10.12.6

[image: vim terminal]

#### 追記

patchが適用された後のvimを使っていますが、こちらの環境ではこの問題は直っていません。
homebrewを使ってvimを再ビルド

```
brew reinstall vim  --with-override-system-vi --with-python3 --with-lua --HEAD
```

したのですがまだ背景色が灰色です。

`--HEAD`を指定しているのでvimのgithub repositoryから最新のpatchを取ってくるようになっています。

再ビルドしたvimの`vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 15 2017 21:17:21)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1111
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminal
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -F/private/tmp/vim-20170915-24424-1xde4d9/Frameworks -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa  -L/usr/local/lib -llua -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl  -L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin -lpython3.6m -framework CoreFoundation  -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

Answer (score 6):

残念ながら現状は、background オプションの dark/light で切り替える以外にはありません。

ただ、今パッチを書いている最中ですのでもうしばらくお待ちください。

**追記1**

パッチは送りましたが、取り込まれるかどうかはまだ分かりません。

https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/2067

**追記2**

マージされました。

https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/c71053c61180ed1ad0c98ba6063b769757832932

https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/69e8aa75112a0b12811a4f4d11061adceffbbabc

Comment: パッチを適用してみましたがこちらの環境ではなぜか直りませんでした

Comment: MacのTerminal.appを使っているのですが、これは24bit colorをサポートしていません。
そのためにtermguicolorsを有効にしていないのですが、それが原因でしょうか?

Comment: OSX 持ってないので確かな事が言えないのですが、TERM=xterm-256color だとどうでしょうか？また t_Co の値は何でしょうか？

Comment: t_Co=256、TERMもxterm-256colorです

Comment: おっと、256色の処理が抜けてますね。来週対応しようと思います。

Comment: と思ったらありました。すいません。termguicolors をオフにして t_Co=256 なら256色のテーブルから色作ってそうですね。ともあれ来週見ます。

Comment: vim-jp/issuesにも報告しておきました

https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/1096

Answer (score 0):

Terminal.appの環境設定を開き、自分が使っているプロファイルを選択し、ANSIカラーの`ホワイト(明)`の色を変更してください。

Webセーフカラーから`#FFFFFF`を選ぶと白くできます。